# trying to display a map with gmap object in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I'm working with JSF2 and I want to display a map with the object gmap. As I saw, gmap object doesn't exist anymore with richfaces 4.x, so I tried to import the gmap4jsf.jar to render my map...

To have an exemple I took a part of my code from the Richfaces demo here : [Richfaces live demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/gmap.jsf;jsessionid=0DD8E6A0722E3392981481479E7940BB?c=gmap&tab=usage)

The map is displayed well, but if I want to control it (change the type, zoom,...) with the jsf elements from the rich:panel, I get an error in Firebug : "map is undefined"...
Can somebody help me to find out the problem please because I didn't find the answer in other thread...
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:m="http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/"><h:head><title>JSF 2.0: Ajax Support</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=myPersonnalKeyIsWrittenHere"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<style>.optionList {height: 30px;}</style></h:head><h:body>
<div id="container">
    <ui:include src="tpl/menu.xhtml" />
    <h1>Gmap4Jsf</h1>
    <div align="center">

        <f:view contentType="text/html">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:form id="mapform" prependId="false">
                    <m:map var="map" mapVar="map" gmapKey="#{gmapBean.gmapkey}" id="map" /> 
                </h:form>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:form>

                        <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax" width="350" height="400">
                            <rich:tab label="Using Google Map API">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="optionList">
                                    <h:outputText value="Controls:" />
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <a href="javascript: void 0" onclick="map.hideControls()">Hide</a>
                                        <a href="javascript: void 0" onclick="map.showControls()">Show</a>
                                        <br />
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                    <h:outputText value="Zoom:" />
                                    <rich:inputNumberSlider id="zoom" showInput="false"
                                        minValue="1" maxValue="18" value="#{gmapBean.zoom}"
                                        onchange="map.setZoom(this.value)" />


                                    <h:outputText value="Map Type:" />
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <a href="javascript: void 0"
                                            onclick="map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP)">Normal</a>
                                        <a href="javascript: void 0"
                                            onclick="map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP)">Satellite</a>
                                        <a href="javascript: void 0"
                                            onclick="map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP)">Hybrid</a>
                                        <br />
                                    </h:panelGroup>

                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </rich:tab>

                            <rich:tab label="Using Ajax with JSON">
                                <rich:dataGrid var="place" value="#{gmapBean.point}"
                                    columns="2">
                                    <h:graphicImage onclick="showPlace('#{place.id}')"
                                        style="cursor:pointer" value="resource://#{place.pic}" />
                                </rich:dataGrid>
                            </rich:tab>
                        </rich:tabPanel>
                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </f:view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it out...

I had to define the name of the Javascript variable generated by JSF.
So, I just added the attribut "jsVariable" to my gmap element.

```
<m:map jsVariable="map" var="map" mapVar="map" gmapKey="#{gmapBean.gmapkey}" id="map" />
```

Bye